# Append a copy of the records in a table if a linked data source changes

Tags: mysql, ms-access, automation

Quick question regarding MySQL/Microsoft Access.

I am trying to build a database that centralises a number of CSV files that are an output of reports.

I would like to make an automated process that when the CSV files change, they are automatically uploaded onto the database.

I have both MS Access and MySQL available to use.

- How could I produce an automated process that uploads the data?

  - I would require the data to be appended when uploaded, not replaced
  - I would need the appended data to be time stamped

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Never ask something like "What ... would be best?" on SO. You are risking that your question gets close voted.

Comment: Thanks Paul, duly noted and changed

Comment: The same applies for "best way". You want a working solution. Does it really matter, if it's the "best way" (what ever it means)? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just link to the files.  When something changes in one of the CSV files, the change will automatically be updated on the Access side.  Here is a VBA script that loops through all CSV files in a folder and creates a link to each.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Call DoImport
End Sub

Function DoImport()

 Dim strPathFile As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

 ' Change this next line to True if the first row in CSV worksheet
 ' has field names
 blnHasFieldNames = True

 ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
 ' contains the CSV files
 strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

 ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
 ' the data are to be imported

 strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")

 Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile

       DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

 ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
 ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
 '       Kill strPathFile

       strFile = Dir()
 Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have implemented it and it works! I have an issue though. It does not append to the data within the database, it replaces it. Is there way to make it so it just adds the new data into the database, without replacing?

Comment: I don't think I saw that ask in your original post.  I'm sure there are a few ways to do this.  You can try:  INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.ID = table1.ID
WHERE table1.ID Is Null;